# JRE bug? JTable contains certain string -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, unicode, crash, fatal-error

A user reported that a certain [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrxJ5Q4w7UM) causes our program to fail. Upon investigation it seems that adding a String containing the title of that video to a JTable causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException somewhere in the rendering code.

We have tested and confirmed this on both Java 7u45 and Java 8 (b121) on Windows XP, 7 and 8, and Ubuntu.

Here is a test program demonstrating the issue:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestJTableAIOOBE {
    private static final String TEXT = "\u0D38\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D40\u0D32\u0D4D\u200D \u0D15\u0D31\u0D3F\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D15\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D3F\u0D2F\u0D3F\u0D32\u0D4D\u200D \u0D2F\u0D47\u0D36\u0D41\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D3F\u0D38\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D41\u0D35\u0D3F\u0D28\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D46 \u0D30\u0D42\u0D2A\u0D02 \u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D2F\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D37\u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D2A\u0D46\u0D1F\u0D4D\u0D1F\u0D41";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Font font = findFont();
                if (font == null) {
                    System.out.println("No suitable font found");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Using font: " + font);
                JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{{TEXT}}, new Object[]{"title"});
                table.setFont(font);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(table);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static Font findFont() {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        for (Font font : ge.getAllFonts()) {
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(TEXT) == -1) {
                return font.deriveFont(0, 12);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This stack trace is printed to stderr every time Swing attempts to render the text:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:814)
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:548)
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getLineBreakIndex(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:480)
    at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.calcLineBreak(TextMeasurer.java:330)
    at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.getLineBreakIndex(TextMeasurer.java:566)
    at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(LineBreakMeasurer.java:359)
    at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(LineBreakMeasurer.java:328)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.clipString(SwingUtilities2.java:472)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabelImpl(SwingUtilities.java:1023)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel(SwingUtilities.java:892)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.layoutCL(BasicLabelUI.java:94)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.layout(BasicLabelUI.java:201)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.paint(BasicLabelUI.java:164)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:777)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2115)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:777)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1062)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5224)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1532)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1455)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1252)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1039)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1973)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3901)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:822)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:794)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1680)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can you reproduce this? What peculiarity in the string actually causes this? Is it really a JRE bug? Should I report it to Oracle?

Comment: This probably is a JDK bug. [Looking at the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/font/ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java#ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo%28%29) it seems to be building a bounding box, so perhaps one of the glyphs returned by the font doesn't behave (perhaps a bad font, but Swing should compensate). To narrow down, I'd suggest progressively removing all instances of a single character code from your test string (eg, remove all `\u0D02`, then all `\u0D15` and so on ... there are 23 of these).

Comment: Also, I'd add a simple ASCII column label to the `JTable`. Shouldn't matter, but best to eliminate a zero-length string as a possibility.

Comment: They already know about it. See  http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=8b833c54cb93d6c9cf416667dc02?bug_id=6374477 and http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5004101 -- allegedly fixed, but apparently not. The bug report might give you more info.

Comment: @kdgregory JDK-6374477 indeed seems pretty similar and it's not fixed. The report is from 2006. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was reported to Oracle in January 2014, and three months later it appeared in the public bug tracker as **[JDK-8041480](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041480)**. The bug was fixed for Java 9 in September 2016.

Answer (score 1):

> We have tested and confirmed this on both Java 7u45 and Java 8 (b121)
>   on Windows XP, 7 and 8, and Ubuntu.

and

> JRE bug?

- not just to remove, replace [`\u200D - ZERO WIDTH JOINER`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) (hint 2times in String)

---

EDIT this is is Font issue (used) for JTable

.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    private String TEXT = "Jesus appear in Knife \u0D38\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D40"
            + "\u0D32\u0D4D\u0D4D\u0D15\u0D31\u0D3F\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D15\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D3F\u0D2F"
            + "\u0D3F\u0D32\u0D4D\u0D15\u0D2F\u0D47\u0D36\u0D41\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D3F\u0D38\u0D4D"
            + "\u0D24\u0D41\u0D35\u0D3F\u0D28\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D46 \u0D30\u0D42\u0D2A\u0D02\u0D2A\u0D4D"
            + "\u0D30\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D2F\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D37\u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D2A\u0D46\u0D1F\u0D4D\u0D1F\u0D41";
    private String _TEXT = "Jesus appear in Knife \u0D38\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D40\u0D32\u0D4D\u200D "
            + "\u0D15\u0D31\u0D3F\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D15\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D3F\u0D2F\u0D3F\u0D32\u0D4D"
            + "\u200D \u0D2F\u0D47\u0D36\u0D41\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D3F\u0D38\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D41\u0D35"
            + "\u0D3F\u0D28\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D46 \u0D30\u0D42\u0D2A\u0D02 \u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D24\u0D4D"
            + "\u0D2F\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D37\u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D2A\u0D46\u0D1F\u0D4D\u0D1F\u0D41";
    private JTable table;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{{_TEXT},},
            new String[]{"Col 1",});

    public Test() {
        table.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 21));
        table = new JTable(model);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062484/jre-bug-jtable-contains-certain-string-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

with generated exception

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Bugs.Test.<init>(Test.java:28)
    at Bugs.Test$1.run(Test.java:42)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

---

EDIT_2 other JComponents (reduced part of, pretty to ignore this chars sequence, but maybe I'm not used proper Font), but Renderers concept is used in this code example

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SystemFontDisplayer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nimbus UIDeafaults and Font");
    private JComboBox fontsBox;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;
    private String buggyConstalation = "Jesus appear in Knife \u0D38\u0D4D"
            + "\u0D31\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D40\u0D32\u0D4D\u200D\u0D15\u0D31\u0D3F"
            + "\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D15\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D3F\u0D2F\u0D3F\u0D32"
            + "\u0D4D\u200D \u0D2F\u0D47\u0D36\u0D41\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D3F"
            + "\u0D38\u0D4D\u0D24\u0D41\u0D35\u0D3F\u0D28\u0D4D\u0D31\u0D46"
            + "\u0D30\u0D42\u0D2A\u0D02 \u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D30\u0D24\u0D4D\u0D2F"
            + "\u0D15\u0D4D\u0D37\u0D2A\u0D4D\u0D2A\u0D46\u0D1F\u0D4D\u0D1F\u0D41";
    private JButton testButton = new JButton(buggyConstalation);
    private JTextField testTextField = new JTextField(buggyConstalation);
    private JLabel testLabel = new JLabel(buggyConstalation);//caused by \u200D
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public SystemFontDisplayer() {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fontFamilyNames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(Locale.getDefault());
        fontsBox = new JComboBox(fontFamilyNames);
        fontsBox.setSelectedItem("SansSerif");
        fontsBox.setRenderer(new ComboRenderer());
        fontsBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    final String fontName = fontsBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    fontsBox.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
                    start();
                }
            }
        });
        fontsBox.setSelectedItem(0);
        fontsBox.getEditor().selectAll();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{{buggyConstalation,buggyConstalation},}, 
                new String[]{"Col 1","Col 2",});
        table = new JTable(model);        
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0, 20, 20));
        frame.add(fontsBox);
        frame.add(testButton);
        frame.add(testTextField);
        frame.add(testLabel);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(200, 105);
        frame.pack();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fontsBox.setPopupVisible(true);
                fontsBox.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(750, updateCol());
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final Font fnt = new Font(fontsBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), Font.PLAIN, 12);
                final FontUIResource res = new FontUIResource(fnt);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.font", res);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TextField.font", res);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Label.font", res);
                UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.font", res);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemFontDisplayer systemFontDisplayer = new SystemFontDisplayer();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ComboRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            final Object fntObj = value;
            final String fontFamilyName = (String) fntObj;
            setFont(new Font(fontFamilyName, Font.PLAIN, 16));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call on the `Font`.. :)

Comment: mKorbel, @AndrewThompson, Further testing revealed that there is no exception if the "Arial Unicode MS" font is *merely installed* on the computer (*no matter which font is actually set* using setFont(...)). This font comes with Microsoft Office and is not included in Windows by default.

Comment: @ntoskrnl  Huh. That is interesting and yes I do definitely have that `Font` installed (and MS Office).

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue when using Code2000.ttf to render Malayalam menu entries.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 280
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:814)
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:548)
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharX(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:357)
```

eventually we figured out that the menu item names had trailing spaces. removing these squashed this issue for us.

..ede